# Insert large amounts of Elements to DOM with Polymer Data-Binding in Dart causes lags

Tags: html, performance, dom, dart

To be honest, I am just waiting for Günter to answer my question (lol) ^_^

Anyhow, I am writing on a project which starts with a pretty huge list of items (1500+). Some of them are used for a selection mask inside DropDowns and about 800 of them are displayed in a grid.

I tried to do the best I can to keep everything fast and smooth but loading the website takes about 20-30 seconds which is a little bit too long.

To address this issue I wanted to make use of `<core-list>` which allows me to render only about 8 items per DropDown instead of all of them. This would reduce the amount of items rendered for DropDowns from 700 to 32. However, I HAVE to use some observables in the DropDowns and since there is a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544403/core-list-dart-how-access-variable-observable-outside-data-attribute#comment47571214_28544403) accessing those I cannot make use of `<core-list>`.

My HTML Code for DropDowns:

```
<div relative flex>
  <paper-input-decorator label="Committee" on-click="{{openDropdown}}" dropdown="{{committeeDropdownId}}">
    <input is="core-input" value="{{committee}}">
  </paper-input-decorator>
  <paper-shadow absolute z="2" class="dropdown" hidden?="{{!openedState[committeeDropdownId] || committees.length < 2}}" style="width: 100%">
    <div id="{{committeeDropdownId}}" style="width: 100%">
      <template repeat="{{item in committees}}">
        <paper-item 
              hidden?="{{!activeCommittees[item['v']] || !containsText(item['k'], committee)}}" 
              on-click="{{onItemSelected}}" 
              value="{{item['v']}}">{{item['k']}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </div>
  </paper-shadow>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have to access `containsText(..)` as well as `activeCommittees` inside the template which would be the template I have to use for `<core-list>`. With that in mind I added `containsText(..)` to my item class which I would use for `<core-list>` and added observable getters for `committee` and `activeCommittees`. Since these getters have to access the 'original' variables I declared these variables static and pretty much everything was dirty and ugly and didn't really work any longer.

**First Question:** So the first part of my question is, can I tweak the performance of the creation of my DropDowns WITHOUT `<core-list>`?

But there is more. There is a grid containing about 800 little 20x20 pixel cells. Constructing this also takes a while.

The grid HTML code looks like this:

```
<div vertical layout>
  <template repeat="{{row in rows}}">
    <div row horizontal layout>
      <template repeat="{{col in row.items}}">
        <template if="{{!col.dummy}}" bind="{{col.delegate as item}}">
          <core-tooltip disabled?="{{!activeMEPs[item['v']]}}">
            <div mep="{{item['v']}}" class="grid-item item" 
                 low?="{{mepFactors[item['v']][0] <= 0.1}}" 
                 style="opacity: {{mepFactors[item['v']][0]}}; background: {{color(item['v'], activeMEPs[item['v']])}};">
            </div>

            <div tip>
              <!-- Name in Tooltip -->
              <h4 style="margin: 0em 0 0.1em;">{{Database[item['v']]['k']}}</h4>
            </div>
          </core-tooltip>
        </template>

        <template if="{{col.dummy}}">
          <div class="grid-item dummy"></div>
        </template>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

This may look more complicated than it is, but I create N rows mit M columns and fill the remaining columns with empty dummy container.

**Second Question**: So here comes the second part of my question, how can I increase the performance of creating my grid?

It's all about performance, right? Thanks for reading the longest post I ever made!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What core-list does to improve performance, is to only render to the DOM what is visible to the user. Everything outside the current view is only rendered when it is scrolled into view. This is usually not trivial work.

Currently development of core-/paper-elements seems a bit stale because of the transition to Polymer 0.8. I doesn't make sense to put too much effort in the 0.5 versions of the elements when a lot of work has to be redone when 0.8 is in a state that more advanced elements can be ported.

Instead of core-list you could try [bwu_datagrid](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/bwu_datagrid) which also has a lot of such optimizations. BWU Datagrid also doesn't use Polymer data binding which is known to be not the fastest possible way to show data on the page. BWU Datagrid also has some issues. For example, it doesn't work well on other browsers than Chrome yet, because I also don't want to put too much effort into it before 0.8 is ready.

If you don't plan to release your application within the next weeks it might make sense to pub such performance optimizations on hold until you get them for free but it is possible that it takes some months until it becomes available.

Comment: It's a project I am helping my sister with for university. Thus the performance is not crucial since it will only be used for two weeks by a couple of people but I was curious how to speed things up. `<core-list>` looks to me like an Adapter in Android which recycles its view. Of course this speeds up the process dramatically but as you pointed out, it's not trivial. I think I will than stick with what I currently have.

Comment: I haven't investigated all measures used in core-list but I know it avoids rendering invisible content. I don't know if they reuse DOM elements. BWU Datagrid reuses the view and just updates the Data in the visible area.